# How does Typescript Annotation Scan Works?

Tags: typescript, express, annotations

I am working on a project where i have implemented annotations to do routing for a express api app. But the I am getting a empty route list at run-time.

I have tried many resources but could not figure out how to do it.

```
// RouteService File
export const routes: {
    path: string,
    router: string[]
}[] = [];

export function GetDynamicRoutes(): string[] {
  let router: string[] = [];
  routes.forEach(route => {
    router = router.concat(route.router);
  })
  return router;
}

// Decorators File
import { routes } from "../service/route.service";
import { AbstractController } from "../controller/abstract.controller";

export function Route(path: string) {
    return function (constructor: Function) {
        routes.push({
            path,
            router: constructor.prototype.router
        });
    }
}

export function RouteRequest(path?: string) {
    return function (target: Object, key: string | symbol,
        descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        if (target.isPrototypeOf(AbstractController)) {
            const router = (target as AbstractController).router;
            const endpoint = path ? path : key.toString();

            router.push(endpoint);
        }
    }
}

// AbstractController file
export class AbstractController {
  public router: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.router = [];
  }
}

// TestController File
import { Route, RouteRequest } from "../decorator/route.decorator";
import { AbstractController } from "./abstract.controller";

@Route('test')
export class TestController extends AbstractController {
    @RouteRequest()
    helloWorld() {
        console.log('inside-hello-world');
    }
}

// Main File
import { GetDynamicRoutes } from "./service/route.service";

function main() {
    const routes = GetDynamicRoutes();
    console.log(routes);
}
main();
```

Here is a Sample Code. Commented are separated files. All imports are done.

[image: Edit youthful-goldwasser-t8byo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Issue that I have had contains two Questions which are,

1. How does Typescript Annotation Scan Works?
2. What is wrong with my code?

To Answer the first Question, The decorator scan always begin from inside. In the order of top to bottom.

```
@Class()
export class Sample {
  @property()
  testVar: string = "hi";

  @method()
  helloWorld() {
    console.log(this.testVar);
  }
}
```

In this example, the order of decorator execution goes as,

1. @property()
2. @method()
3. @Class()

You can check a working example with the link below,

[image: Edit xenodochial-forest-i2zz6]

To answer the next question.

Can use a decorator scanner for this purpose. A decorator scanner is just a file that exports all files that contains decorators.

Working Solution.

[image: Edit lively-meadow-houoj]